# mutex работает крайне медленно

Tags: c++, многопоточность, mutex

Всем здравствуйте! Пытаюсь создать параллельный алгоритм на с++. До этого пользовался многопоточностью WinAPI, я использовал класс Event и функции WaitForSingleObject, WaitForMultipleObjects. Сейчас стоит задача переписать тот код, избавив его от WinAPIшных функций. Логика взаимодействия потоков с основным потоком следующая: основной поток выполняет чтение данных, затем дочерние потоки выполняют параллельную обработку этих данных, после чего сохранение данных выполняет основной поток. Приведенный код работает, но проблема в том, что невероятно медленно. Если код с использованием WinAPI работает 3 секунды, то этот код работает аж 12 секунд!

P.S. избавляться от algorithm пробовал, это не дало эффекта абсолютно

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


int numOfThreads = 4;
std::vector<bool> vstart(numOfThreads, true);
std::mutex mx;
std::condition_variable cv;
int counter = 0;
int yMax = 228, yCurrent = 0;
bool stop = false;

void threadMethod(int it)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mx);
    while (true)
    {
        // поток ждет сигнала для начала работы
        vstart[it] = 0;
        cv.wait(lk, [it] {return vstart[it]; });

        if (stop)
            break;
        std::cout << counter << "\n";
    }
}

void main()
{
    // потоки создаются один раз перед основным циклом
    std::vector<std::thread> vt;
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfThreads; ++i)
    {
        vt.emplace_back(threadMethod, i);
    }

    // основной цикл
    for (; yCurrent < yMax; ++yCurrent)
    {
        while (std::any_of(vstart.begin(), vstart.end(), [](bool n) {return n == true; }))
            ;
        {
            // основной цикл выполняет потоконебезопасные действия, пока остальные потоки "спят"
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg{ mx };
            ++counter;

            // основной цикл посылает сигналы в дочерние потоки для старта
            std::fill(vstart.begin(), vstart.end(), true);
        }
        cv.notify_all();
    }

    while (std::any_of(vstart.begin(), vstart.end(), [](int n) {return n == true; }))
        ;
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg{ mx };
        std::fill(vstart.begin(), vstart.end(), true);
        stop = true;
    }
    cv.notify_all();

    for (auto& t : vt)
    {
        t.join();
    }
}
```

Рабочий код на WinAPI:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int numOfThreads = 4;

HANDLE* hThreads;
HANDLE* hStartEvents;
HANDLE* hDoneEvents;
int counter = 0;
int yMax = 228, yCurrent = 0;

DWORD WINAPI threadMethod(LPVOID lParam)
{
    int threadNumber = (int)lParam;
    while (yCurrent < yMax)
    {
        // поток ждет сигнала для начала работы
        WaitForSingleObject(hStartEvents[threadNumber], INFINITE);

        // сбрасывает флаг начала работы
        ResetEvent(hStartEvents[threadNumber]);

        // выполняет действия
        std::cout << counter << "\n";

        // сообщает о завершении
        SetEvent(hDoneEvents[threadNumber]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void main()
{
    // -= СОЗДАНИЕ CОБЫТИЙ СТАРТА И ОСТАНОВА =-
    hStartEvents = new HANDLE[numOfThreads];
    hDoneEvents = new HANDLE[numOfThreads];
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfThreads; i++)
    {
        hStartEvents[i] = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
        hDoneEvents[i] = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    }

    // -= СОЗДАНИЕ ПОТОКОВ =-
    hThreads = new HANDLE[numOfThreads];
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfThreads; i++)
    {
        hThreads[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, threadMethod, (LPVOID)i, 0, nullptr);
    }

    for (yCurrent = 0; yCurrent < yMax; yCurrent++)
    {
        // основной поток выполняет потоконебезопасные действия
        counter++;

        // основной поток высылает сигналы начала работы
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfThreads; i++) SetEvent(hStartEvents[i]);

        // оснвной поток "спит", пока выполняются дочерние потоки
        WaitForMultipleObjects(numOfThreads, hDoneEvents, TRUE, INFINITE);

        // сброс флагов событий завершения
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfThreads; i++) ResetEvent(hDoneEvents[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `any_of` обращается к элементам вектора без синхронизации

Comment: Я пробовал избавиться от any_of и вектора, делал массив и функцию, которая проходится циклом по элементам массива и работает аналогично. Но это совсем не ускорило программу. Задача в том, чтобы код с использованием mutex работал хотя бы не больше чем в 2 раза медленнее WinAPI.

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что программа имеет состояние гонки, что является неопределенным поведением. Так что прежде, чем делать программу быстрой, ее надо сделать корректной.

Comment: `threadMethod целиком бежит под mutex mx;` - так `any_of` там не вызывается, речь про `main` шла

Comment: Рабочий код WinAPI добавил. Я бьюсь над этим уже больше недели, и это - единственный вариант, который у меня хотя бы заработал. Очень хотел бы увидеть, как правильно

Comment: Избавляйтесь от пустых циклов. Вы вообще понимаете, что цикл `while (...) ;` при условии без побочных эффектов НИКОГДА не будет работать быстро?

Comment: Теоретически я это понимаю, но практически не могу найти нормальной документации, где написано, как работать std-шной многопоточностью(((

Comment: Этот пример я находил. К сожалению, это не то, что мне нужно. Мне нужно, чтобы основной цикл посылал потокам разрешение на обработку, ждал их, а по завершении сам обрабатывал результаты, пока дочерние потоки спят. Никак иначе нельзя. Помогите мне, пожалуйста))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не нужно писать пул потоков самостоятельно. Например (решение через future):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <future>
#include <algorithm>



int counter = 0;
std::mutex mx; // protect std::cout and ::counter.

int numOfThreads = 4;
int yMax = 228, yCurrent = 0;



void threadMethod(int it)
{
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mx);
        std::cout << "begin " << counter << " from " << it << "\n";
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds(1));

    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mx);
        std::cout << "end " << counter << " from " << it << "\n";
    }
}

void main()
{
    // потоки создаются один раз перед основным циклом

    std::vector< std::future<void> > futures;
    futures.reserve( numOfThreads );


    // основной цикл
    for (; yCurrent < yMax; ++yCurrent)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg{ mx }; // Здесь лочить не обязательно, поскольку все потоки ждут std::async-f , но пусть будет для единообразия.
            ++counter;
        }

        for( int it=0; it<numOfThreads; ++it )
            futures.push_back(  std::async( threadMethod, it ) );

        for(auto& f : futures) // wait for all
            f.wait(); // get()  если нужен результат вычисления из threadMethod
        futures.clear();    
    }
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за попытку помочь! К сожалению, этот код работает всё те же 12 секунд(((

Comment: 12 секунд  для данного кода - совершенно нереальное время. (У меня и оба варианта вашего кода и мой - отрабатывают за тысячные доли секунды.) Возможно, вы измеряете время под отладчиком, или с подключенной библиотекой контроля утечек памяти, или включаете время компиляции в измеряемое время...

Comment: Нет-нет. Здесь код приведен как пример, я же его пытаюсь внедрить в гораздо более сложную задачу (если вдруг интересно, фильтр для картинки, просто реально нет смысла в рамках этого узкого вопроса обсуждать мои цели).

Comment: У меня возникло подозрение, что в Вашем примере потоки выполняются не параллельно, а все-таки последовательно. Не могло так выйти, что весь threadMethod - это критическая секция?...

Comment: Они будут выполняться параллельно, если число процессоров достаточно. (async не порождает больше потоков чем процессоров, во всех известных мне реализациях.) Убедиться что потоки исполняются параллельно можно поменяв вложенную задачу.  (поправил пример.)

Comment: ОГРОМНЕЙШЕЕ СПАСИБО! Жму Вам руку! Вот из этого примера я всё понял и всё заработало как надо. Просто спасибище!!! К сожалению, так как я новичок на форуме, я не могу даже добавить Вам + к репутации(( но благодарю от всего сердца! Это - именно то, что я искал 2 недели. /thread